# How to mock System.getenv() for Java17 with JUnit5?

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock `System.getenv()`. That's how I am doing it with https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules lib:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SampleTest {
   @Rule
   public final EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables = new EnvironmentVariables();
   @BeforeEach
   public void setup() {
       environmentVariables.set("AWS_REGION", TEST_REGION.toString());
       environmentVariables.set("CLIENT_ACCOUNT_ROLE", ROLE_ARN);
   }
   ...
}
```

But build fails with exception:  `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Map java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module`. The exception happens in the line `environmentVariables.set("AWS_REGION", TEST_REGION.toString());`.

I found similar problem for another annotation https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer/issues/509 but there is no proper solution for it. Is there a way to mock variables for this java and junit version?

Comment: Write a component for retrieving environment variables and mock it, don't access them directly.

Comment: thanks, I already have that but I wanted to add tests for this component as I need a higher code coverage

Comment: I suggest that you make that component trivial and don't test it. All it needs is a single method to call `System.getenv()`

Answer (score 2):

System Rules does not support Java 17. The fork/extension to it - System Stubs - does.

https://github.com/webcompere/system-stubs

```
public class SomeTestClass {
    @Rule
    public EnvironmentVariablesRule rule = new EnvironmentVariablesRule();
}
```

You can set the environment variables either in the initialiser of the rule, in your `@Before` or during your test.

The library comes with support for JUnit4, JUnit and the `system-lambda` mechanisms too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get pre-Java16 behavior, you can use

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

in your JVM args. Using `build.gradle.kts` this looks something like

```
withType<Test> {
    ...
    jvmArgs("--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED")
}
```